# Why do I get 0 instead 1 in after fork?

Tags: c, linux, fork

I have the program that increases the number by one.

```
int ile=0;

pid_t pid = fork();

if(pid != 0) {
  ile++;
  printf("%d", ile);  //I get 1
} 
else {
  printf("%d", ile);  //I get 0  
}
```

Why do I get 0? I must get 1.

Comment: Add `\n` to each of your printfs...

Comment: *" I should get 1"* Why do you think so?

Comment: You should get both, in undefined (possibly, but not necessarily random) order, either `01` or `10`. Unless fork fails, and returns only once with `-1`, then you would get only `1`.

Comment: Ok, no should, i must get 1, because i need this. How do this?

Comment: The question makes no sense... Perhaps you should put `fork()` return value to temp variable, and test for 3 choices: `-1`, `0` and `>0`

Comment: values ​​will not be only 0 and 1 She can be any number, to 100

Comment: Are you doing homework which create upto 100 children processes? We can't help you unless explain in detail.

Comment: Also, perhaps you should show complete code, `main()` function or something. Now it seems you may have some loop or something around that piece of code, if you talk about going up to 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fork ()` creates a new process with its own address space. These are not threads that share a common address space. If you want the latter behavior look at something like `pthreads`.

Changes in the parent process (`ile++` in your case) after a `fork()` isn't going to be visible in the child.

Comment: So what is the solution ?

Comment: @user3062986 you can try moving `++ile` to happen in the parent process, before every fork, so each `fork`ed child process is going to have a different value (when parent process changes its variable after fork, already created child processes do not see the change).

Comment: Global variabels aren't shared across **processes**. If you really can't set this stuff up before fork, then you need to use threads!